# Is a finite dimensional vector space always countable?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a vector space of finite dimension, can we always find an injective map to the natural numbers?

z.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is a one-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, is this true in ZF+AD?

Comment: @alancalvitti: The reals are always uncountable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, what about in ZF?  1. Vector spaces may have no bases. 2. Vector spaces may have two bases with diﬀerent cardinalities. (Herrlich *AC*)

Comment: @alan: The concept of dimension is not well defined in ZF. It is true that if the ultrafilter lemma holds then all bases must have same cardinality (we do not require them to exist of course). In ZF, or the absence of a choice principle implying such property we should say "no finitely generated" or "not generated by any set of size $X$".

Comment: Furthermore what Brian wrote is always true. Every field is a one dimensional vector space over itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends over what field. If the field is finite or countable, e.g. $\mathbb Q$, then yes. If the field is uncountable, e.g. $\mathbb R$, then no.

The reason is that $|\mathbb F^n|=|\mathbb F|^n$, and if $|\mathbb F|\leq\aleph_0$ then $|\mathbb F|^n\leq\aleph_0$.